# Passing and Receiving Arguments Using Getx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm trying to pass arguments when moving from one window to another using Getx routing. During the transition, I pass one Uint8List:

`Uint8List jpeg = Uint8List.fromList(img.encodeJpg(image)); Get.toNamed(RoutesClass.getPreviewRoute(), arguments: jpeg);`

In the receiving class, I do the following:

`Uint8List jpeg = Get.arguments;`

to display the resulting image I use the following:

`decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage( fit: BoxFit.cover, image: MemoryImage(controller.jpeg),)),)`

But the jpeg in the receiving class is always empty. What did I miss and why is my jpeg empty? When

When trying to display a jpeg from the arguments, I observe the following:

[image: screenshot]

But if I try to display the jpeg on the first screen, then I see the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the jpeg in the onInit method of the receiving class's controller:

```
  @override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    jpeg = Get.arguments;
  }
```